# Can I calculate playtime in Divinity: Original Sin

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I need help with something. 
I started playing Divinity: Original Sin some three months ago.

The thing is, I would really love to know how many hours I spent on this playthrough, because I think it might be among my longer RPG experiences. But I played it offline, non-cooperative, single-player only. Is there a way to retroactively calculate played time? Any way? Through game saves or some sort of logs on my computer? Are there records somewhere on my PC as to how long an application was "active"? Is there a tool that could dig through my databases?
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Raptr.com maybe?

Comment: Did you install via Steam

Comment: No, unfortunately, didn't install it via Steam, and I don't know if Raptr can calculate played times retroactively, just using a game profile, last saved game or anything like that. Cause I was playing offline the whole time, and it's a single player game.

Comment: That is not possible. NO software can retroactivly calculate the time you spent playing a game unless there are precise logs when you launched and exited.

Comment: The only way is to look at the Windows Logs, seeing when you opened and closed the *.exe, and use some mathematical calculations to find out how long it took. Next time, either use Raptr.com OR Add the game as a non-steam game, and then it should start recording from there.

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen I don't think Windows Logs kept log on when you 'closed' a program.

Comment: @deutschZuidL I think Windows records when a program is "Terminated", regardless of user intervention or not, but I am not exactly sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about calculating running-time of an executable.

Comment: I might try the Windows records approach... There was a theory that you can convert the days in-game - and you have those listed next to every save - to real time, something like "day in-game equals 3 hours of real time" but that doesn't account for all those times you loaded a game after a mini-boss wipes the floor with you. :) And I don't even know if the conversion was accurate. So, Win logs are still my best option. :)

Comment: @Krkynn, thats great :D I just added my response to the answers so others who have the same problem can see it too.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: It seems that, at lease for the PS4 version, 4 hours of real life play session equates to one day in the in-game world. So you could easily find how many days have elapsed within the game world, multiple by four, and get how many hours you have spent in game. This should apply to PC as well

*Courtesy of @MartinEnder for finding that out!*

---

**As you have not installed it via steam, and you are only playing offline single-player, there is no easy way of getting your answer**

---

## So what can I do?

The only possible ways are:

- *Looking at the time in-game, and calculate the offset you need to multiply to get the real time. An easy way is to play 10 minutes IRL, and see how much time passed in-game. This will give you the number you need to multiple to get your answer*
- *Look at the Windows Logs (assuming you are using windows) and see when you opened and terminated (close) the *.exe. If you use a Mac, then you would need the appropriate logs Mac uses to track the change in programs. If you don't know how to access the logs:*

  - Ask on the Super User Stack Exchange page. They should be of great help.
    **DO NOT ASK HERE, IT IS IRRELEVANT FOR GAMING AND WILL BE CLOSED AS SUCH**
  - Use your search provider, should give the same answers

---

## Recomendations

I would recommend you to add the game on Steam, even as a non-steam game. This will allow Steam to still track how long you have played, without you needing to dig into the logs

Comment: Awesome compilation of answers, thanks for that! When I find the time, I'll try both - or rather all three - approaches and let you guys know how it went. That way I'll even be able to compare and control them.

Comment: That's great @Krkynn. If you think the answer helped, please click the Tick button so other people can see that your question was answered. And more rep+ for me ;)

Comment: On it @MartinEnder :)